# Search and replace REL attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to search links and replace their `rel` attributes if the `rel` attribute currently equal `attachement`.

The code I have so far is:

```
$("href").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('rel', 'group');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to test the rel value against something (let's say "attachment"), all you have to do is something like this:

```
$('a[rel="attachment"]').attr('rel','group');
```

This says that for all `<a>` elements with `rel="attachment"`, set `rel` to "group".

On the other hand, if what you mean to change is all elements with an `href` attribute, you'll use something like

```
$('[href][rel="attachment"]').attr('rel','group');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('rel', 'group')
});
```

Not sure what you're trying to test the value of 'rel' against.

Answer (score 0):

no such selector as `href`

try:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rel', 'group');
});
```

Comment: `href` *is* a valid [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) that would select any element that’s name is *href*. But there is just no *href* element in HTML.

Comment: @Gumbo. thats what i meant :-p

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean equals `"attachment"`?

```
$("a").each(function(index) {
    // href is `this.href`
    if(this.rel == 'attachment') 
        $(this).attr('rel', 'group');  
});
```